# Vectorize filtering on matlab cell structures

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a huge cell vector cc (size: 1xN) of the form:

```
cc{1} = {'indexString1', 'str_row1col1', 'str_row1col2' }
cc{2} = {'indexString2', 'str_row2col1', 'bighello', 'str_row1col3' }
cc{3} = {'indexString3','str_row3col1'}
cc{4} = {'indexString4','str_row3col1', 'helloWorld'}
```

I want to traverse each cell and remove specific cells that contain the word "hello", e.g `c{4}{2}`. Can we do that without for loops keeping the final structure of `cc`?

Best,
Thoth.

**EDIT:** From the answers and comments I have seen that the structure of the cell impose some limitations. So any other suggestion to store my data are welcome. I just want to keep together all the cells (e.g. `'str_row1col1', 'str_row1col2'`) that correspond to the same indexString*n* (e.g. `indexString1`). I made this edit in case it helps some final reshape.

Comment: Do you mean remove `cc{4}` or `cc{4}{2}`?

Comment: Sorry if it unclear, I am interested to remove cc{4}{2}, i.e, a specifiv call not the row that bellongs. Thanks for you observation, I made appropriate changes on the post.

Comment: It would be easier if the cells were not nested. Still, vectorizing is difficult with cells (`cellfun` is more or less a loop so it doesn't count as vectorizing)

Comment: I made some edits tha may help, I hope.

Comment: Why not use loops?  This sort of variable-length data and string processing is not likely to benefit from vectorization.  Keep it clean and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can obtain a logical array in which zeros represent occurences of the word 'hello' somewhere in the nested cell. As @LuisMendo pointed out, this would be much easier to delete the unwanted cells if they were not nested:

```
clc
clear

cc{1} = {'str_row1col1', 'str_row1col2' };
cc{2} = {'str_row2col1', 'bighello', 'str_row1col3' };
cc{3} = {'str_row3col1'};
cc{4} = {'str_row3col1', 'helloWorld'};

A = (cellfun(@isempty,regexp([cc{:}],'(\w*hello|hello\w*)','match')))
```

Gives the following array:

```
A =

     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
```

For the rest I think you would need a loop since the nested cells are not all of the same size. Anyhow I hope it helps you a bit.

**EDIT** Here is what you can do using a for loop. In order to identify words of interest (earth and water as in your comment below), simply add them to the argument in the call to regexp. This character: | is used to make some sort of list so that Matlab checks all the expressions in the brackets.

Please refer to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) page for more infos on regular expressions. There is also a possibility to look for regular expressions with case-sensitivity.

Sample code, in which I added strings containing earth and water:

```
cc{1} = {'str_row1col1', 'earth!superman' 'str_row1col2' 'DummyString'};
cc{2} = {'str_row2col1', 'bighello', 'str_row1col3' };
cc{3} = {'str_row3col1' 'str_row3col3' 'water_batman'};
cc{4} = {'str_row3col1' 'str_row4col2' 'helloWorld'};
cc{5} = {'str_row5_LegoMan' 'str_row5col2' 'AnotherDummyString' 'Useless String' 'BonjourWorld'};


% With a for loop, for example:
FinalCell = cell(size(cc,2),1);

for k = 1:size(cc,2)  

    DummyCell = cc{k}; % Use dummy cell for easier indexing

    % This is where you tell Matlab what words/expressions you are looking for
    A =  cellfun(@isempty,regexp(cc{k},'(\w*hello|hello\w*|earth|water)','match'));

    DummyCell(~A) = []; % Remove the cells containing the strings/words of interest
    FinalCell{k} = DummyCell;    
end
```

Then you're good to go. Hope that helps!

Comment: I think I will adopt your logic, but how can we search multiple strings? Like `hello`, 'earth' and 'water'?Thanks!!

Comment: I just edited my answer hopefully this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing possible I found is:

```
clear all

cc{1} = {'str_row1col1', 'str_row1col2' };
cc{2} = {'str_row2col1', 'bighello', 'str_row1col3' };
cc{3} = {'str_row3col1'};
cc{4} = {'str_row3col1', 'helloWorld'};

cc1 = [cc{:}];
cc1 = cc1(~strcmp('bighello',cc1));
```

This reorganize your array into a one dimensional array and it cannot match regular expression, but only whole words.
For a better job I am afraid you have to use for loops.

Comment: I am interested to keep the same structure of the `cc`.

Comment: then I don't think is possible without a for loop.